# How to write a macro to match slightly different match statements?

Tags: rust, macros, pattern-matching

I have match statement like

```
match self{
X::A(x) => x.call_me(),
X::B(x) => call_me(),
X::C(x) => call_me(),
X::D(x) => call_me(),
X::Z(x) => x.call_me(),
}
```

Can i write two macros then join them somehow in a single match statement ? If not how would i write two types of patterns one with A&Z other with B,C,D in single macro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling a macro per line, you want to make a single macro that encloses them all:

```
macro_rules! the_macro {
    ($($alone:ident),* ; $($withx:ident),*) => {
        match self {
            $( X::$alone(_x) => call_me(), )*
            $( X::$withx(x) => x.call_me(), )*
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
the_macro!(B, C, D; A, Z);
```